# Initialize a variable object in Angular2 / Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm coming from Angular 1 where I'd just do this:

```
var options = {};
options.location = "test";
options.time = "today";
```

I just want to do the same thing with Angular 2 to sorta "group" my variables by adding them to objects and using interpolation to reference them in the HTML

```
<input [(ngModel)]="options.location" />
```

Now I already figured I could do this:

```
export class Options {
  location: string;
}

options: Options = {
  location: 'test'
};
```

My question: Is there a simpler way like

```
options: {location: string};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `options: {location: string};` or the Angular 1 way you mentioned?

Comment: Yep, when I try to assign it in the constructor via `this.options.location = "test"`it says `this.options is undefined`in the console...

Answer (score 6):

Typescript can be considered as extended JavaScript. Any valid JavaScript code is valid Typescript code.

The code you wrote in your question :

```
var options = {};
options.location = "test";
options.time = "today";
```

...is perfectly legal (but not optimal).

The thing is that simply declaring `options` the way you do in the component won't make it visible from the template. `options` must be a **public** member of the `Component` class. 
Your `Component` class should look like

```
@Component({
  template: `
<input [(ngModel)]="options.location" />
`})
export class FormsPage {
  options = {location :"test", time : "today" }
}
```

Note that if I were you, I would read [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html) (and even JavaScript one) in addition to Angular2's one. It would help you to better understand how handle it.

Answer (score 4):

Found it myself -

```
this.options = {location: "test"};
```

instead of

```
this.options.location = "test"
```

Not sure why the second version does not work. If you have insight please share in the comments!

Comment: For the 2nd you would first need `this.options = {};` You can't assign to `location` of something that doesn't exist (like in the first code snippet in your question)

Comment: This is basic JavaScript and is not related to Angular2 or even typescript

Answer (score 1):

To initialize a `ngModel` value in angular , Create a class **Options** like this:

**Options.ts**

```
export class Options {
  location: string;
  time: string;
  constructor(location: string, time: string) {

  }
}
```

Or

```
export class Options {
  location: string;
  time: string;
  constructor(location: string, time: string) {
    this.location = location;
    this.time = time;
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="location" [(ngModel)]="options.location" #location="ngModel" required/>

<input type="text" name="time" [(ngModel)]="options.time" #time="ngModel" required/>
```

And in your **component** initialize `options` like this:

```
options = new Options('','');
```

**NOTE**: if you create `Options` class like this:

```
   export class Options {
      constructor(location: string, time: string) {

      }
    }
```

It will work with `ng serve` but **NOT** with `ng build --prod` as AOT(Ahead-of-Time) compilation gives error:

```
ERROR in ng:/xxxx/x.component.html (67,74): Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Options'.
ERROR in ng:/xxxx/x.component.html (72,72): Property 'time' does not exist on type 'Options'.
```

If you initialize `options` in component in this way

```
options={};
```

will also gives same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
options: Options = {
  location: 'test'
} as Options;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this options:

```
Options = new Options ({ location :"test", time : "today"  });
```